# Why content loaded by ajax has href modified

Tags: jquery, ajax

So, I have a content that is loaded by ajax. When it is loaded, then the "next" page href is modified as below:

**Normal href : Not loaded by Ajax**

The pagination that is **not loaded by ajax** has following `href` setup:

```
<a href="http://example.com/page/2/">2</a>
```

**href modified: Content is loaded by ajax**

The pagination that **is loaded by ajax** has following `href` setup:

```
<a href="http://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.phppage/2/?action=royal_front_tab&amp;id=dhvc_id">2</a>
```

**Summary**

**Working (Good):**

```
<a href="http://example.com/page/2/">2</a>
```

**Not working (Bad):**

```
<a href="http://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.phppage/2/?action=royal_front_tab&amp;id=dhvc_id">2</a>
```

Since there is no such page as in "bad" href, I get 404.

So my question is that, why is it happening when the content is loaded by ajax?
Also, is there a fix for this? or jQuery "hack" to revert it back?

Thanks!

**/////////////////////////////////////////////////////**

**EDIT: Complete code**

Idea: Load the a div content by ajax then load the `next` page content within the same div by infinite scroll.

**Step 1. Loading it by ajax:**

- Idea is that `#dhvc_id` is clicked when the page is first loaded, then the `id` is given to the function.php which locates the appropriate file then parse it on the same div.

**demo.php**

```
<?php
/**
* Template Name: Demo
*/

get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
        <div class="dhvc_demo" id="dhvc_id"></div>              
    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>

<script>

 //To trigger initial click
 jQuery(window).load(function() { 
    jQuery("#dhvc_id" ).trigger( 'click' );  
    return false;       
    }); 
 //Ajax loading
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#dhvc_id').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var tab_id = jQuery(this).attr('id'); 

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>", 
            dataType: 'html',
            data: ({ action: 'royal_front_tab', id: tab_id}),
            success: function(data){
                  jQuery('.dhvc_demo').html(data);


        },
        error: function(data)  
        {  
        alert("Error!");
        return false;
        }  

        }); 

 }); 
 }); 

</script>
```

**Function.php**

```
//Ajax call for front page
function royal_front_tab_callback() {  
$template_part_path = 'page-parts/01_home_' . $_GET['id'];
get_template_part($template_part_path);
exit;
}
add_action('wp_ajax_royal_front_tab', 'royal_front_tab_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_royal_front_tab', 'royal_front_tab_callback');
```

**01_home_dhvc_id.php**

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[some_shortcode]'); ?>
```

So, This itself works just fine (Ajax works fine).

**Step 2. Loading the next content by infinite scroll:**

I followed the instruction from here: http://wptheming.com/2012/03/infinite-scroll-to-wordpress-theme/

**Function.php**

```
function custom_theme_js(){
wp_register_script( 'infinite_scroll',  get_template_directory_uri() . '/custom_js/jquery.infinitescroll.min.js', array('jquery'),null,false );
wp_enqueue_script('infinite_scroll');

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_theme_js');

function custom_infinite_scroll_js() {
{ ?>
<script>
jQuery('.royal_card.dhvc-woo-row-fluid.dhvc-woo-grid-list').infinitescroll({
    navSelector  : jQuery('.dhvc-woo-pagination'),
    nextSelector : jQuery('.dhvc-woo-pagination > a.next'),
    itemSelector :  '.royal_card.dhvc-woo-row-fluid.dhvc-woo-grid-list >    .royal_card_outer.royal_card_content_grid',
    contentSelector: jQuery('.royal_card.dhvc-woo-row-fluid.dhvc-woo-grid-list'),
msgText: "fdfgdg "  
},function(newElements){
    jQuery('.dhvc-woo-separator').remove();
    jQuery('.royal_card.dhvc-woo-row-fluid.dhvc-woo-grid-list >  .royal_card_outer.royal_card_content_grid').after('');
});
</script>
<?php
}
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_infinite_scroll_js',100 );
```

This works just fine as well, only when the content is not initially loaded by the ajax.

Here is what I mean:

**Scenario 1: Just infinite scroll (content is not loaded by ajax): Works fine**

See the working example at http://sevek.staging.wpengine.com/dhvc_working-demo/

The pagination that is **not loaded by ajax** has following `href` setup:

```
<a href="http://sevek.staging.wpengine.com/dhvc_working-demo/page/2/">2</a>
```

**Scenario 2: Both Ajax loading and infinite scroll (content is loaded by ajax)<--This is what I am trying to achieve but the href of the pagination (inspect element) is modified**

You can see the example from http://sevek.staging.wpengine.com/dhvc-test/ and inspect the element at the bottom of the page, where pagination should be there.

The pagination that **is loaded by ajax** has following `href` setup:

```
<a href="http://sevek.staging.wpengine.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.phppage/2/?action=royal_front_tab&amp;id=dhvc_id">2</a>
```

As you can see, when the content is loaded by ajax, the href becomes somewhat odd, and it now contains `"wp-admin/admin-ajax.phppage"` in the href, which does not exist and the infinite scroll cannot find it.

So, when I checked the element inspector, I got the following `"modified"` script .

**Modified Script**

```
 //To trigger initial click
 jQuery(window).load(function() { 
    jQuery("#dhvc_id" ).trigger( 'click' );  
    return false;       
    }); 
 //Ajax loading
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#dhvc_id').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var tab_id = jQuery(this).attr('id'); 

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://sevek.staging.wpengine.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", 
            dataType: 'html',
            data: ({ action: 'royal_front_tab', id: tab_id}),
            success: function(data){
                  jQuery('.dhvc_demo').html(data);

                jQuery('.dhvc-woo-row-fluid.dhvc-woo-grid-list').infinitescroll({
                        navSelector  : jQuery('.dhvc-woo-pagination'),            
                        nextSelector : jQuery('.dhvc-woo-pagination > a.next'),    
                        itemSelector :  '.dhvc-woo-row-fluid.dhvc-woo-grid-list > .dhvc-woo-row-fluid',
                        contentSelector: jQuery('.dhvc-woo-row-fluid.dhvc-woo-grid-list'),
                        msgText: " "
                    },function(newElements){
                        jQuery('.dhvc-woo-separator').remove();
                        jQuery('.dhvc-woo-row-fluid.dhvc-woo-grid-list > .dhvc-woo-row-fluid').after('<div class="dhvc-woo-separator"></div>');
                    });
        },
        error: function(data)  
        {  
        alert("Error!");
        return false;
        }  

        }); 

 }); 
 });
```

For the scenario 2, the second page should be "`http://sevek.staging.wpengine.com/dhvc-test/`page/2", whereas `/dhvc-test/` is missing from the modified href when it is loaded by ajax.

I am thinking perhaps I can use jquery to `"hack"` the href back to "normal".

Comment: Try executing http://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.phppage/2/?action=royal_front_tab&amp;id=dhvc_id independently in a browser

Comment: I got "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" error. So, this is what I am trying to do (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32061336/how-to-have-infinite-scroll-within-ajax-loading). I am loading contents by ajax, and trying to add infinite scroll, but because href is modified it is not working.

Comment: Please try and check the url once...for the working one `http://example.com/page/2/` there is a **/** before page and for the non-working one `"http://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.phppage/2/?action=royal_front_tab&amp;id=dhvc_id` rewrite it as `"http://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php/page/2/?action=royal_front_tab&amp;id=dhvc_id` and try

Comment: Yeah,, it shows me a broken page.  Such a weird behavior.  So, for the working version, `example.com/demo` becomes `example.com/demo/page/2`. It retains the original url. However, with the ajax, it does not look like it retains the `/demo/` part. Do you think there is a jQuery hack to change the href back to the `example.com/demo/page/2` ?

Comment: I don't quite get it. So what is **supposed to** be shown after the ajax call?

Comment: Well, in the initial Ajax loading, only about 5 posts are shown, in which the next contents are shown by infinite scroll. The infinite scroll works by loading the page 2 contents. However since the href is modified in the Ajax loading, it can't load the page 2 contents.

Comment: @EmilyTurcato, could you plz let us see your ajax call too? and also, what are the exact hrefs generated? Or your example.com examples are actually legit, you have just changed the domain name?

Comment: Please show the code that triggers the ajax call and the code that makes the ajax call. That is essential to know to be able to help.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. I have added the complete code for both ajax and infinite scroll with working examples. =) Thank you so much! I really need help with this :P

Comment: So, any suggestions? :P